# K3S multi node clsuter - application not accessible . gateway time out error

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, ghost-blog, k3s

I have the below K3S set up and have ghost application running on baremetal server. I am accessing the application from my myblog.mysite.io .

When I access the site I get a 504 gateway timeout error. WHen I remove the pods from the worker node, the application is accessible indicating a networking issue or load balancer issue. I am using traefik as a loadbalancer .

I dont know how to troubleshoot further and resolve this. Any help is much appreciated.

```
kubectl get nodes -o wide
NAME                 STATUS   ROLES                  AGE    VERSION        INTERNAL-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE                         KERNEL-VERSION     CONTAINER-RUNTIME
amd-deb           Ready    control-plane,master   4d1h   v1.27.6+k3s1   192.168.178.100   <none>        Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)   6.1.0-13-amd64     containerd://1.7.6-k3s1.27
intelnuc-ubuntu   Ready    <none>                 4d     v1.27.6+k3s1   192.168.178.50    <none>        Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS               6.2.0-34-generic   containerd://1.7.6-k3s1.27
rpi-wn-mon           Ready    <none>                 4d     v1.27.6+k3s1   192.168.178.10    <none>        Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)   6.1.21-v8+         containerd://1.7.6-k3s1.27
rpi-wn-gv            Ready    <none>                 4d     v1.27.6+k3s1   192.168.178.20    <none>        Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)   5.10.103-v7+       containerd://1.7.6-k3s1.27
```

```
kubectl get all --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE      NAME                                           READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system    pod/local-path-provisioner-957fdf8bc-6rr9p     1/1     Running   0          4d1h
kube-system    pod/svclb-traefik-5df69c3a-khjrv               2/2     Running   0          4d
kube-system    pod/svclb-traefik-5df69c3a-2w298               2/2     Running   0          4d
kube-system    pod/svclb-traefik-5df69c3a-hm28k               2/2     Running   0          4d
kube-system    pod/svclb-traefik-5df69c3a-67pv2               2/2     Running   0          4d
cert-manager   pod/cert-manager-cainjector-744cb68868-srlkj   1/1     Running   0          3d23h
cert-manager   pod/cert-manager-webhook-5f58d6bf86-slvw7      1/1     Running   0          3d23h
kube-system    pod/coredns-77ccd57875-mjng8                   1/1     Running   0          3d23h
cert-manager   pod/cert-manager-8694c7d4fd-mhvxx              1/1     Running   0          3d23h
kube-system    pod/metrics-server-648b5df564-7zrs6            1/1     Running   0          4d1h
traefik        pod/traefik-77c6b44c4b-9ktjj                   1/1     Running   0          31h
ghost          pod/ghost-6b4fff7c54-rrxnj                     1/1     Running   0          69m
ghost          pod/ghost-6b4fff7c54-dcgsq                     1/1     Running   0          68m

NAMESPACE      NAME                           TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP                                                    PORT(S)                      AGE
default        service/kubernetes             ClusterIP      10.43.0.1       <none>                                                         443/TCP                      4d1h
kube-system    service/kube-dns               ClusterIP      10.43.0.10      <none>                                                         53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP       4d1h
kube-system    service/metrics-server         ClusterIP      10.43.9.81      <none>                                                         443/TCP                      4d1h
traefik        service/traefik                LoadBalancer   10.43.60.145    192.168.178.10,192.168.178.100,192.168.178.20,192.168.178.50   80:31852/TCP,443:30968/TCP   4d
traefik        service/traefik-dashboard      ClusterIP      10.43.196.176   <none>                                                         9000/TCP                     4d
cert-manager   service/cert-manager-webhook   ClusterIP      10.43.55.22     <none>                                                         443/TCP                      3d23h
cert-manager   service/cert-manager           ClusterIP      10.43.57.208    <none>                                                         9402/TCP                     3d23h
ghost          service/ghost-service          ClusterIP      10.43.109.150   <none>                                                         2368/TCP                     33h

NAMESPACE     NAME                                    DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR   AGE
kube-system   daemonset.apps/svclb-traefik-5df69c3a   4         4         4       4            4           <none>          4d

NAMESPACE      NAME                                      READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
kube-system    deployment.apps/local-path-provisioner    1/1     1            1           4d1h
cert-manager   deployment.apps/cert-manager-cainjector   1/1     1            1           3d23h
cert-manager   deployment.apps/cert-manager-webhook      1/1     1            1           3d23h
kube-system    deployment.apps/coredns                   1/1     1            1           4d1h
cert-manager   deployment.apps/cert-manager              1/1     1            1           3d23h
kube-system    deployment.apps/metrics-server            1/1     1            1           4d1h
traefik        deployment.apps/traefik                   1/1     1            1           4d
ghost          deployment.apps/ghost                     2/2     2            2           31h

NAMESPACE      NAME                                                 DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
kube-system    replicaset.apps/local-path-provisioner-957fdf8bc     1         1         1       4d1h
cert-manager   replicaset.apps/cert-manager-cainjector-744cb68868   1         1         1       3d23h
cert-manager   replicaset.apps/cert-manager-webhook-5f58d6bf86      1         1         1       3d23h
kube-system    replicaset.apps/coredns-77ccd57875                   1         1         1       4d1h
cert-manager   replicaset.apps/cert-manager-8694c7d4fd              1         1         1       3d23h
kube-system    replicaset.apps/metrics-server-648b5df564            1         1         1       4d1h
traefik        replicaset.apps/traefik-77c6b44c4b                   1         1         1       4d
traefik        replicaset.apps/traefik-8bfb89767                    0         0         0       31h
ghost          replicaset.apps/ghost-6b4fff7c54                     2         2         2       69m
ghost          replicaset.apps/ghost-767475c696                     0         0         0       31h
```

```
kubectl get pods -n ghost -o wide
NAME                     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP           NODE                 NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
ghost-6b4fff7c54-rrxnj   1/1     Running   0          72m   10.42.1.65   intelnuc-ubuntu   <none>           <none>
ghost-6b4fff7c54-dcgsq   1/1     Running   0          72m   10.42.0.61   amd-deb           <none>           <none>
```